# Finding the contraction of a spring when a body falls on it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring

A mass of 5 kg is released from a 20 m height from the ground. A spring of height 1 m and spring constant 5000 $J/m^2$ is positioned below the mass. The question asks what the maximum compression of the spring due to the body will be.

My teacher did it this way:
The kinetic energy of the body right before it touches the spring, $E_k$ = $mgs$, where s is the distance travelled by the body beforehand. So, $E_k$ = 5 * 9.8 * 19 = 931 J. When the body eventually stops going downwards due to the upwards force of the spring, the total energy it will have given the spring will be equal to this $E_k$, so it's equal to 931 J.
Now, energy of the spring, $E$ = $1/2kx^2$ where $x$ is the compression of the spring. So, $x$ = $sqrt(2E/k)$, which is equal to $sqrt(2 * 931 / 5000 )$ = 0.610 m.

According to my teacher's solution, the energy given to the spring is equal to the kinetic energy of the body right before it touches the spring. However, as the body continues to move downwards from the tip of the spring to the height where it eventually stops, which is $1-x$ m (since the height of the spring is 1 m and its compression is $x$ m), a part of its gravitational potential energy is getting converted to kinetic energy, which in turn is being given to the spring. So, shouldn't the total energy given to the spring be equal to kinetic energy of the body right before touching the spring + this potential energy which is being turned to kinetic energy after the body reaches the tip of the spring?

Comment: You have to account for the loss of gravitational potential energy after the mass contacts the spring.

Comment: So when the mass touches the spring, it loses its gravitational potential energy and thus no new kinetic energy is produced from potential energy? But why? It's the same as if the mass were on a surface at a height of 1 m, in which case it would still have a potential energy

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need to take into account the potential difference between the initial position and the final position. This should be equal to the elastic energy of the spring at maximum compression. Considering the KE is an unnecessary step in the calculation.
If the spring deformation is small (very stiff spring) compared with the initial height you may neglect the potential energy change during deformation.
You can calculate both ways and see what error you make by neglecting this part in gravitational PE. Here you have a height of 20 m and the deformation you get is 0.61 m. Anyway, the deformation cannot be more than 1 m. So it is an error of less than 1/20 or 5% in the PE estimation. This may be why he neglected the last term in PE. It may be also that if you don't you get a quadratic equation in x and maybe you did not learn how to deal with these.